# How to catch an unhandled exception in Windows Azure (Worker) Role

Tags: c#, exception, azure

I'm trying to catch all unhandled exceptions in my worker role. I tried putting a `try`-`catch` block into the `Run()` method (as suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/11019f45-0ab6-403b-8908-fa40766af875)) but with no success.

```
public override void Run()
{
  try
  {
    base.Run();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Trace.TraceError("Unhandled Exception: {0}", ex);    
    throw ex;
  }
}
```

The role hosts a WCF service, so there is no other logic inside the `Run()` method. Is there another possibility to catch exceptions at this level?

**Update 1**
To clarify the problem: The role self hosts a WCF service (initialized in `OnStart()`) where some operations are background operations. When the service is called and that method throws an unexpected exception, I like to catch that to write it to the log.

**Solution:**
Obviously it is like in a normal C# application:
Just add a handler to the `UnhandledException` event like this

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
  new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

inside the `OnStart()` of the Role. I was so focused on Azure that I supposed this couldn't work after all, that I didn't even try it :-)

Comment: Try this with a dummy worker role that simply throws `new Exception("Testing");`

Comment: The role hosts a WCF service, so there is nothing really inside the Run() method. Should have mentioned that.

Comment: @gumo: ok, then add the throw before the base.Run.

Comment: @John: That exception is of course catched.

Comment: @gumo: then ask yourself, why would the exception you're trying to catch not be catchable, but just plain `Exception` (and any class derived from `Exception`) not be catchable? I'll give you a few minutes to answer that yourself.

Comment: @John: Thanks for your help, but that's not the point.

Comment: I've found a simple solution, see above.

Comment: @gumo: what was the exception and why couldn't it be caught?

Comment: @John: It could be any exception, for example an IOException that is thrown by a background operation in the role. I think it can't be caught in the Run() because it isn't called there. Does that answer your question? thanks again.

Comment: @gumo: I guess the fact that you posted the `Run` method confused me. Please update your question to show how the service is hosted. That will make it clear that the exception wasn't caught in the catch because it didn't happen within the try.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As already updated in my question, here for completeness's sake as answer:

Obviously it is like in a normal c# application: Just add a handler to the `UnhandledException` event like this

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
   new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

inside the `OnStart()` of the Role.

Answer (score 0):

The catch will catch all exceptions.

You are throwing it again so that one will not be caught.

Also you are logging, but logs are not turned on by default in Azure, since they cost.

The other alternative is that there is no exception.