# Prevent unhandled exceptions from tearing down Azure worker role

Tags: .net, azure, azure-worker-roles

We have an Azure worker role that runs a heavily async workload, with lots of completions on IO threads and the like.

Occasionally, unhandled exceptions occur on async callbacks that we don't own. This in turn causes the role to fail.

In non-Azure ASP.NET applications, we can avoid this by enabling the legacy unhandled exception policy in aspnet.config like this:

```
<configuration> 
  <runtime> 
    <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1" /> 
  <runtime>
<configuration>
```

Is there a way to do the same for the Azure worker role? We attempted to place this in the app.config for the role project, but that did not work (since we probably have to get it into the WaWorkerHost.exe.config somehow).

We're aware of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`, and `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode`, and [How to catch an unhandled exception in Windows Azure (Worker) Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626638/how-to-catch-an-unhandled-exception-in-windows-azure-worker-role) and these don't solve our issue.

Comment: Still looking for an answer! Please chime in.

Answer (score 0):

Just read your thread, cause I experience the same with a webrole. Now I added your code snippet and check if I will experience this error again. Did some research about the AppDomain class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx. As a matter of fact I was searching for the unhandled exception policy but have not found it. But I found the event "UnhandledException" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx.

But you wrote this doesnot work. Cause this will hit me later on as well - I will run a 3rd party open source component in an azure worker role - I did some research.

I will try to create a new AppDomain for the 3rd pary code - and if an exception occurs, it will crash/unload the newly created AppDomain and not the current I run the code in. Another solution would probably be creating a new process, which is I suppose more work.

EDIT:
I revisited this topic: in version 2.0 it was introduced to tear down the application domain in case a thread (not main thread) experience an error in a class library. It seems that even a seperate ApplicationDomain will not help. As I understood this design should help debugging errors hidden in libraries by catch exceptions on library level and handle them appropriately. But what irritates me - what happens if we use 3rd party class libraries we have no control of? Then it seems we are stuck if our issue is to small for the vendor to resolve it in time necessary for us.

Comment: Marc, I am looking for a better answer if possible, one that doesnt require managing appdomains (its not desireable for us to lose appdomain state when it gets torn down), or creating own own process.